# Is Ubuntu viable for a company of 5 employees and 20 or so clients?

Tags: server

Linux appears to be a viable solution for my new and growing business.  The problem is that I am having an impossible time learning if it should be what I invest in without running into a sustained barrage of geek language (Juju?? Yum?? Stop it with the weird names already it's very distracting).  I am hoping for answers at the business owner level.

Can I set it up and let it run with a modest (meaning business owner level not full time IT fluent Linuxer that goes to all the tech conferences) amount of effort?

Can I set up my own cloud of collaboration for my team and clients?  Do I have to have my entire team switch to LibreOffice?

Online meetings.  Top priority.  Can I host my own online meetings or do I have to find a cloud solution like Webex or Join.me?

Desperately want to escape the insanity of Microsoft but I don't want to doom my new and growing business with an immature or unwieldy solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

Linux, Ubuntu specifically, is designed for ease of use. However there is no guarantee that you won't run into something that you'll need help with. I have no trouble with it, but in the least, hire a tech guy. As for cloud (online services) Ubuntu is pretty much universally compatible with anything you could possibly need. About LibreOffice, you don't need to be "stuck" with it, Google docs (as well as any other google service) work perfectly with Ubuntu.

In short, it's up to you. check out [Ubuntu's business page](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/business) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, for an employee strength of 5, you would be better off with Google Apps than Microsoft or Ubuntu. It is cost effective and also has several benefits like strong collaboration applications like online meetings (Hangouts - lets you do screen sharing, audio and video conferencing , the works), integrates awesomely with android, ios or windows phones for email, calendar and contacts. For online meetings, you also have Uber extension for the browser. Works like charm.

From a desktop or a laptop perspective - either move your people to chrome book or you can continue to use windows or Ubuntu or Mac. Google apps can be used right off the browser - any browser. Lets you sync with local machine - for any OS.

For 5 people organization, setting up Ubuntu or  Microsoft infra and maintaining a sys-admin does not make commercial sense - both from hardware and sys-admin perspective.

You can consider Ubuntu for desktop use - but if none of the guys in your company are a bit tech savvy, you should continue with whichever OS you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of business do you have?  If your clients accept having their data, communications, and work you do for them on the cloud then the Gdocs and associated approaches could be  viable.  If there are compliance, audit, and such associated with your work, you would have to think through the implications.

I run Linux as a virtual machine on a Mac.  This is for learning different OS-es and general experimentation.  I've tried several flavors of Linux and I would only pick them for a business if the employees are technically savvy, know at least one distribution, and can get questions answered for themselves on forums like this and others.  There are so many flavors and sub-flavors of distributions and dependencies that a small business could wind up in a bind.

Mac Minis could be a good option for you to consider.  Relatively low cost, stable OS built on Linux, good 3rd party software including a LOT of open source, can run Linux on them if you want, etc.